# IronPython and Nodebox in C#

Tags: c#, python, opengl, ironpython, nodebox

**My plan:**

I'm trying to setup my C# project to communicate with Nodebox to call a certain function which populates a graph and draws it in a new window.

**Current situation: [fixed... see Update2]**

I have already included all python-modules needed, but im still getting a

> `Library 'GL' not found`

it seems that the `pyglet` module needs a reference to `GL/gl.h`, but can't find it due to IronPython behaviour.

**Requirement:**

The project needs to stay as small as possible without installing new packages. Thats why i have copied all my modules into the project-folder and would like to keep it that or a similar way.

**My question:**

Is there a certain workaround for my problem or a fix for the library-folder missmatch.
Have read some articles about `Tao-Opengl` and `OpenTK` but can't find a good solution.

***Update1:***

Updated my sourcecode with a small pyglet window-rendering example. Problem is in pyglet and referenced c-Objects. How do i include them in my c# project to be called? No idea so far... experimenting alittle now. Keeping you updated.

***SampleCode C#:***

```
ScriptRuntimeSetup setup = Python.CreateRuntimeSetup(null);
ScriptRuntime runtime = new ScriptRuntime(setup);
ScriptEngine engine = Python.GetEngine(runtime);

ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("test.py");
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
source.Execute(scope);
```

***SampleCode Python (test.py):***

```
from nodebox.graphics import *
from nodebox.graphics.physics import Vector, Boid, Flock, Obstacle

flock = Flock(50, x=-50, y=-50, width=700, height=400)
flock.sight(80)

def draw(canvas):
    canvas.clear()
    flock.update(separation=0.4, cohesion=0.6, alignment=0.1, teleport=True)
    for boid in flock:
        push()
        translate(boid.x, boid.y)
        scale(0.5 + boid.depth)
        rotate(boid.heading)
        arrow(0, 0, 15)
        pop()

canvas.size = 600, 300

def main(canvas):
    canvas.run(draw)
```

***Update2:***

Line 139 [pyglet/lib.py] sys.platform is not win32... there was the error. Fixed it by just using the line:

```
from pyglet.gl.lib_wgl import link_GL, link_GLU, link_WGL
```

Now the following Error:

```
'module' object has no attribute '_getframe'
```

Kind of a pain to fix it. Updating with results...

***Update3:***

Fixed by adding following line right after first line in C#-Code:

```
setup.Options["Frames"] = true;
```

Current Problem:

`No module named unicodedata`, but in `Python26/DLLs` is only a `*.pyd` file`. So.. how do i implement it now?!

***Update4:***

Fixed by surfing: [link text](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Python/Windows/pyExcelerator/pywin32-214/isapi/test/build/bdist.win32/winexe/temp/unicodedata.py.htm) and adding `unicodedata.py` and `'.pyd` to C# Projectfolder.

Current Problem:

'libGL.so not found'... guys.. im almost giving up on nodebox for C#.. to be continued

***Update5:***

i gave up :/ workaround: c# communicating with nodebox over xml and filesystemwatchers. Not optimal, but case solved.

Comment: found following article about `_getframe` : http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/1042?ProjectName=ironpython
And i still dont know how to fix it.. what does -X:Frame option mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-X:Frames enables the frames option as runtime (it slows code down a little to have access to the Python frames all the time).

To enable frames when hosting you just need to do:

```
ScriptRuntimeSetup setup = Python.CreateRuntimeSetup(new Dictionary<string, object>() {
    { "Frames", true }
});
```

Instead of the null that you're passing now.  That's just creating a new dictionary for the options dictionary w/ the contents "Frames" set to true.  You can set other options in there as well and in general the -X:Name option is the same here as it is for the command line.

Comment: any helping answer is a better then no answer. I'll accept it.